# speech to text on iOS continually makes same mistake

Tags: siri, voice-dictation, ios

As a person who uses speech to text very often, I need a reliable method of conversion. While I know this technology is not perfect, but I keep running into the same error and wonder if there is something I can do. Here is the problem:

I have a friend named Kasey, and when I refer to this person while using dictation, the speech to text engine will output `K.C.`99% of the time

In an attempt to remedy this, I went to Settings/General/Keyboard/Text Replacement and inputted the following rules:

- KC Kasey
- K.C Kasey
- K.C. Kasey

What's interesting is that if I say Kasey at the start of the sentence the speech to text output will be correct. I found a possible solution that worked for someone else [HERE](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8562569), but I can't navigate to those settings with the version of iOS that I have

My presumption here is that text replacement only works while typing, and does not affect text that is generated from speech. If this is the case, how can I remedy my problem?

Using iOS 15.7.5 on Iphone7

Comment: I suspect that speech-to-text input is bypassing the keyboard system and going directly into the text field, which means that the replacement rules will do nothing.

Answer (score 42):

Ok finally found something that worked for me. From [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8613382) Apple Community site:

- add person whose name is being incorrectly translated as a contact with the correct spelling.
- edit the contact, and scroll down to the “add field” and select that.
- Choose the field “pronunciation first name”
- Use the voice dictation to say their name (while in the last field)
- save the contact.

This worked for me.

Comment: This is a great workaround!  Fantastic finding a solution to this issue and posting so others can find a solution.

Comment: This worked for me! Nice one! ;)